# Mock resttemplate getbody returns null pointer exception

Tags: mockito, resttemplate

I have a class which invokes a rest service using resttemplate.

```
Class MyService{
  RestTemplate resttemplate = new RestTemplate();

 public void handler(){
   string token;
    token = restTemplate.exchange(authurl, HttpMethod.POST, getHttpEntity(tenantLogin, basicAuth), String.class)
          .getBody();
}

 private static <T> HttpEntity<T> getHttpEntity(T jsonRequest, String authorization) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Authorization", authorization);
    return new HttpEntity<T>(jsonRequest, headers);
  }
}
```

For above my test class is as below.

```
Class restTemplateTest{

 RestTemplate restTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);

  Field fieldReflectionUtil = 
  ReflectionUtils.findField(Myservice.class, "restTemplate");
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(fieldReflectionUtil);

    ReflectionUtils.setField(fieldReflectionUtil, handler, restTemplate);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    List<String> payload = new ArrayList<>();

  when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<HttpMethod> eq(HttpMethod.POST),
        Mockito.eq(new HttpEntity<>(payload.toString(), headers)), Mockito.<Class<Object>> any()).getBody())
            .thenReturn(Mockito.anyString());


}
```

restemplate getbody() is giving nullpointer exception.

Is there something wrong in the way resttemplate is mocked.

Thanks,
Anjana.

Comment: you cannot do this `.thenReturn(Mockito.anyString());` You should return some dummy String

Comment: .thenReturn(Mockito.anyString()) too returns null pointer when call to getBody is invoked on restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<HttpMethod> eq(HttpMethod.POST),
        Mockito.eq(new HttpEntity<>(payload.toString(), headers)), Mockito.<Class<Object>> any())

Comment: try this `when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<HttpMethod> eq(HttpMethod.POST),
        Mockito.eq(new HttpEntity<>(payload.toString(), headers)), Mockito.<Class<Object>> any()).getBody())
            .thenReturn("dummyString");
`

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to return some dummy string or json string.

```
String token="$11234qwer";

 when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<HttpMethod> 
 eq(HttpMethod.POST),
 Mockito.eq(new HttpEntity<>(payload.toString(), headers)), Mockito.<Class<Object>> 
 any()).getBody()).thenReturn(token);
```